# How to copy top and remaining values to different cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

[image]

I would like to select the top 10 Values from Main table and paste in different range (E3) and REMAINING all values and PASTE and SUM in another range(I3)
I used the code below. It is working for Top 10 values, BUT for remaining, 
when i am adding one more row in Main table, it is not working. Help me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Calculation for Top 10 Countries
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-9, -2).Resize(10, 3).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3")

'Calculation for Remaining Countries
Range("A3:C14").Copy Range("I3")
Range("I15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Remaining"
Range("J15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-12]C:R[-1]C)"
Range("K15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-12]C:R[-1]C)"
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to change the 15's for the `.end(xlUp)` method otherwise it will overwrite the last entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long, Rl As Long                      ' last row

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        R = Application.Max(Rl - 9, 3)
        ' pick Top 10 Countries
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(R, "A"), .Cells(Rl, "C"))
        Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(3, "E")

        ' pick remaining countries
        If R > 3 Then
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(R - 1, "C"))
            Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(3, "I")

            ' write totals
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(3, "J"), .Cells(Rl, "J"))
            Rl = Rl + 1
            With .Cells(Rl, "I")
                .Value = "Remaining"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
            With .Cells(Rl, "J")
                .Value = Application.Sum(Rng)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
            With .Cells(Rl, "K")
                .Value = Application.Sum(Rng.Offset(0, 1))
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your code @variatus . Its working. But when i delete some countries aand calculated for the second time, 
the old values are not deleting. So please change your code and add this code below "' pick remaining countries" to your program. 
It will be helpful to others. 

  If Range("I3") <> vbNullString Then
  Range("I3", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3).ClearContents
  End If

Comment: I thought of that yesterday but didn't implement because of the formatting applied to the totals. There is no telling where those formats would end up when a new list is written into the same cells. Today I posted a new answer which addresses that question and some others, including the one why the top one (of the top 10) is listed at the bottom :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim pr As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'Calculation for Top 10 Countries
        .Range("A" & (lr - 10) & ":C" & lr).Copy .Range("E3")

        'Calculation for Remaining Countries
        .Range("A3:C" & (lr - 11)).Copy .Range("I3")
        pr = .Range("A3:C" & (lr - 11)).Rows.Count + 3
        .Range("I" & pr).Value = "Remaining"
        .Range("J" & pr).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-12]C:R[-1]C)"
        .Range("K" & pr).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-12]C:R[-1]C)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below first sorts the main table by country (hard-coded option), then creates 2 copies of the sorted table in columns E and I sorted descending or ascending (hard-coded option), and deletes the part in each which isn't needed. The user can choose the year by which the ranking is to be determined, and the program allows for more years to be added to the main table and processed without change of code. You may wish to change the name of the worksheet in the code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' 14 Nov 2017

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim ClmCount As Long
    Dim SortYear As Long                            ' = column in main table
    Dim SortOrder As XlSortOrder
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rl As Long, Rend As Long                    ' last row
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    Set Ws = Worksheets("Deepak")
    SortYear = YearToSort(Ws)
    If SortYear Then                                ' exit if cancelled
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Ws
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Rl > 3 Then                          ' skip, if no list
                ClmCount = MainTableColumnsCount(Ws)

                ' === Sorting the main table
                '     you can sort on another column, in another order
                '     or skip the sort entirely
                '     to skip remove these two lines of code
                Set Rng = Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(Rl, ClmCount))
                SortRange Rng, 1, xlAscending       ' sort Main by country (column 1)

                ' === set the sort order for Lists 1 & 2 here:-
                SortOrder = xlAscending             ' Alt: change for xlDescending
                SheetSetup Ws, SortYear, SortOrder  ' create sorted copies

                ' List 1: delete all but the top 10
                C = ClmCount + 2
                R = IIf(SortOrder = xlAscending, 3, 13)
                Rend = IIf(SortOrder = xlAscending, Rl - 10, Rl)
                Set Rng = Range(.Cells(R, C), .Cells(Rend, C + ClmCount - 1))
                Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp

                ' List 2: delete the top 10
                C = 2 * (ClmCount + 1) + 1
                R = IIf(SortOrder = xlAscending, Rl - 9, 3)
                Rend = IIf(SortOrder = xlAscending, Rl, 12)
                Set Rng = Range(.Cells(R, C), .Cells(Rend, C + ClmCount - 1))
                Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp

                ' write totals
                Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Row
                With .Cells(Rl + 1, C)
                    .Value = "Remaining"
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
                For C = (C + 1) To (C + ClmCount - 1)
                    Set Rng = Range(.Cells(3, C), .Cells(Rl, C))
                    With .Cells(Rl + 1, C)
                        .Value = Application.Sum(Rng)
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
                Next C
            End If
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SortRange(Rng As Range, _
                      SortColumn As Long, _
                      SortOrder As XlSortOrder)
    ' 14 Nov 2017

    With Rng.Worksheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Rng.Columns(SortColumn), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=SortOrder, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Rng
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Private Function YearToSort(Ws As Worksheet) As Long
    ' 14 Nov 2017
    ' return the column number of the main table
    ' return 0 if cancelled

    Dim Fun As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim UserInput As String

    Set Rng = Ws.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, MainTableColumnsCount(Ws)))
    ' use B2 as default
    Do
        UserInput = InputBox("Enter the year to sort by:", _
                             "Select a year", Rng.Cells(1).Value)
        If UserInput = "" Then Exit Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Fun = Application.Match(CLng(UserInput), Rng, 0)
        If Err Then
            MsgBox "There is no data for year " & UserInput & "." & vbCr & _
                   "Please enter an available year.", _
                   vbInformation, "Invalid input"
            UserInput = ""
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Loop While UserInput = ""
    YearToSort = Fun + 1
End Function

Private Sub SheetSetup(Ws As Worksheet, _
                       SortYear As Long, _
                       SortOrder As XlSortOrder)
    ' 14 Nov 2017

    Const Captions As String = "Top 10 countries,All other countries"
    Dim Rng As Range, SortRng As Range
    Dim ClmCount As Long
    Dim Rl As Long                      ' last row
    Dim C As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Ws
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ClmCount = MainTableColumnsCount(Ws)
        C = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If C > ClmCount Then
            ' delete all existing except main table
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, ClmCount + 1), .Cells(Rl, C))
            Rng.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rl, ClmCount))

        ' create two copies of the main table
        For i = 1 To 2
            C = (ClmCount + 1) * i + 1
            Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, C)
            .Cells(1, C + 1).Value = Split(Captions, ",")(i - 1)
            Set SortRng = Range(.Cells(3, C), .Cells(Rl, C + ClmCount - 1))
            SortRange SortRng, SortYear, SortOrder
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Private Function MainTableColumnsCount(Ws As Worksheet) As Long
    ' 14 Nov 2017

    Dim Fun As Long

    Do
        Fun = Fun + 1
    Loop While Len(Ws.Cells(2, Fun).Value)
    MainTableColumnsCount = Fun - 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with formulas as well. In the G3 cell type:

```
=LARGE(C$3:C$200, ROW()-2)
```

for finding the top country. In F3 and E3 insert:

```
=INDEX(B$3:B$200, MATCH(G3,C$3:C$200,0))
```

and

```
=INDEX(A$3:A$200, MATCH(G3,C$3:C$200,0))
```

respectively. Then drag then down to 12th row. You have top 10 now. In the cell K3 type:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(C$3:C$200, ROW()+8),"")
```

and in J3 and I3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$3:B$200, MATCH(K3,C$3:C$200,0)),"")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$3:A$200, MATCH(K3,C$3:C$200,0)),"")
```

Then drag then down several screens. There is less than 200 countries and territories on the world, so it should be enough. If there is no macros, you don'tneed the button, everything will update on fly.

Comment: Won't there be a problem if two values in G:G happen to be identical?

Comment: You are right @Variatus. Problem when there is two identical value